# TableView não exibe os dados com JavaFx

Tags: javafx

Bom dia, estou montando um layout com tableView carregado com informações do banco de dados e FXML, ao executar percebi que o tableview recebe os valores do meu dao pois ele exibe exatamente a quantidade de linhas vinda da query, ao fazer um foreach e os dados estão ok, porém o tableview aparece sem as linhas preenchidas.
Fonte: controller

```
public class TableViewController {
private TagsDAO dao;
private List<Tags> tagsList;
//private DateTimeFormatter fomatador = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
@FXML
private TableView<Tags> tbv1;
@FXML
private void initialize(){
    //obtém o objeto DAO
    dao = DAOFactory.getTagsDAO();
    // Adiciona um listener para ser notificado quando o usuário seleciona um item na tabela.
    // Dessa forma é possível definir os bindings corretamente.
    loadData();
}
private void loadData(){
    try {
        tagsList = dao.load();    
        ObservableList<Tags> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(tagsList);    
        tbv1.setItems(list);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Método DAO

```
public List<Tags> load() {
    try (Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.openConnection()) {
        sql = "SELECT dt.Tag, dt.Id FROM DadoTag dt ORDER BY dt.Id ASC";
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        // executa a busca
        try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
            List<Tags> tags = new ArrayList<>();

            // para cada registro encontrado na tabela, cria um objeto
            // Tag e coloca na lista
            while (rs.next()) {
                Tags tagsModel = new Tags();
                tagsModel.setDescTag(rs.getString("Tag"));
                tagsModel.setId(rs.getInt("Id"));
                tags.add(tagsModel);
            }

            return tags;
        }

    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
    alert.setTitle("...");
    alert.setHeaderText("Erro");
    alert.setContentText(e.toString());
    alert.showAndWait();
    throw new DAOException(e);
}
```

}

FXML:

```
<TableView fx:id="tbv1" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="9.0" prefHeight="215.0" prefWidth="316.0">
          <columns>
            <TableColumn text="TAG" prefWidth="100">
                <cellValueFactory property="TAG"/>
            </TableColumn>
          </columns>
        </TableView>
```

Comment: Veja se isso te ajuda: http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/pt/part2/

Comment: Bom dia, obrigado pela resposta, eu já tinha visto o tutorial e tentando fazer desta forma e mesmo assim não obtive sucesso. Grato pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Dentro do seu método List load()

já tentou popular as colunas da tableview para somente depois retorná-la?

Por exemplo:

Coluna "NOME" (clName)

clName.setCellValueFactory(data->data.getValue().getName());

E na classe da respectiva entidade, por exemplo:

public class Person {

private final StringProperty Name;

public Person(String Name) {
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(Name);

```
}

public String getName() {
    return Name.get();
}

public void setName(String Name) {
    this.Name.set(Name);
}

public StringProperty NameProperty() {
    return Name;
}
```

}

Desta forma teu método ficaria:

```
 public List<Tags> load() {
     try (Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.openConnection()) {
         sql = "SELECT dt.Tag, dt.Id FROM DadoTag dt ORDER BY dt.Id ASC";
         try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
         // executa a busca
         try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
             List<Tags> tags = new ArrayList<>();

             // para cada registro encontrado na tabela, cria um objeto
             // Tag e coloca na lista
             while (rs.next()) {
               Tags tagsModel = new Tags();
               tagsModel.setDescTag(rs.getString("Tag"));
               tagsModel.setId(rs.getInt("Id"));
               tags.add(tagsModel);
            }

           **//populando a coluna Name da TableView
           clName.setCellValueFactory(data->data.getValue().getName());**

           return tags;
       }

   }
```